# Multiple directives [x, y] asking for isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have 2 directives on an element. Each works independently of each other. I am aware of the 1 scope per element restriction. I don't understand why this violates it.

Directive X (priority 100) takes an object and uses it to add other directives to the element and removes itself.

```
<div x="obj1"></x>
```

turns into:

```
<div ng-model="x.value" ... ></div>
```

The definition for directive X is:

```
scope: { x: '=' },
replace: false,
link: ...
```

Directive Y (priority 99) makes an element into a widget and takes an ng-model.

```
<div y ng-model="scopeStringValue"></div>
```

turns into:

```
<div y ng-model="scopeStringValue">
    <input ng-model="scopeStrinValue" />
    ...
</div>
```

The definition for directive Y is

```
scope: true,
replace: true,
link: ...
```

What I want is to use them together so that directive x will provide the ng-model for directive y but I get the namesake error.

```
<div y x="obj"></div>
```

should first turn into:

```
<div y ng-model="x.value"></div>
```

and then into:

```
<div y ng-model="x.value">
    <input ng-model="x.value" />
    ...
</div>
```

I don't understand why these directives can't work together.

Comment: This may be useful why it does not work.

http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to declare `scope: false` on directive X and assign the new attributes according to the parent scope (which is used in place of a new scope).

Additionally I had to set terminal to true on directive X otherwise directive Y would get evaluated twice. Once during the manual $compile in directive X then once on its own after. Not sure why it does that but `terminal: true` prevents it.

```
replace: false,
scope: false,
terminal: true,
```

So:

```
<div y x="obj"></div>
```

first turns into:

```
<div y ng-model="obj.value"></div>
```

and finally into:

```
<div y ng-model="obj.value">
    <input ng-model="obj.value" />
    ...
</div>
```

Originally the directive X link function looked like

```
attributes.$set('ng-model', 'x.value');
element.removeAttr('x');
$compile(el)(scope);
```

and now it looks like

```
attributes.$set('ng-model', attrs.fieldSettings + '.value');
element.removeAttr('x');
$compile(el)(scope);
```

*Removing the x attribute is not relevant to this problem but in case anyone is wondering why it is there: it is because we are manually $compiling and this would cause an infinite loop of evaluating the X directive.*